# Android app design need a way to send data from phone to phone

Tags: java, android

Hi I have this idea for a app which will have information like your name, mobile number, email, company address etc like what would be on a business card. Now what I want to happen is when someone has this app on there phone and they want to get the information from the other persons phone with the same app on it, like swapping business cards, how would I go about doing that.

I don't know whether to use qr codes or a barcode or Bluetooth or NFC. If anyone would help me with this and/or link me to some information on how to go about adding this into my app that would be a great help.

Thanks Toby

Comment: NFC seems to be the best solution as it works even when Wi-Fi and Bluetooth is off.

Comment: Yes that was what I was thinking but doesn't that limit the amount of people that can use the app significantly

Comment: Maybe use NFC if available, and fall back to Bluetooth if not.  I'm guessing most devices have that, though you could have a third fallback position if you wanted.  Some sort of wifi connection maybe.

Comment: NFC, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi Direct are all valid options. As nasch said, you can have a fallback according to priority. But I'm pretty sure nearly all devices have NFC built in (except iPhones of course, which only work with Apple Pay).

Comment: Could anyone link me to some tutorials which would help me implement a system in the app where it uses nfc to transfer information from one user to the user.